# Are both Access-Control-Allow-Headers: ["Cookie"] and Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true needed for CORS with cookies?

Tags: javascript, express, http

In some examples, I've seen that only the options (`{ credentials: true, origin: "http://example.com" }`) are needed, but according to MDN, `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` indicate which HTTP headers can be used during the actual request. As for `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`, MDN says that when used as part of a response to a preflight request, this indicates whether or not the actual request can be made using credentials.

Given that cookie is defined as a credential and as a HTTP header, do I only need one of them as options for the cors middleware:

`allowedHeaders: ["Cookie"]` (`Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Cookie` for HTTP)

`credentials: true` (`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` for HTTP)

Or are both needed?

Comment: This is like saying POST and PATCH HTTP methods are the same, and can be used to achieve the same purpose, (to mutate data). So why I don't use only POST requests instead of PATCH and POST requests.

Answer (score 0):

In this post https://jakearchibald.com/2021/cors/ Jake mentioned:

> This started getting complicated in 1994 with the advent of HTTP
> cookies. HTTP cookies became part of a set of things we call
> credentials, which also includes TLS client certificates (not to be
> confused with server certificates), and the state that automatically
> goes in the Authorization request header when using HTTP
> authentication.

With this information, I used github to see how cors is used across repos (https://github.com/search?o=desc&q=Access-Control-Allow-Headers%3A&s=indexed&type=Code).

From there I saw that the headers used are credentials without "Cookie".

Another thing that might help mitigating cors is the playground that Jake built available at https://jakearchibald.com/2021/cors/playground